# Scala sortBy Missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala

I have created a list of lists like this and I can sort this easily on size.

```
@ List(List(2, 2, 3), List(7)).sortBy(_.size)
res71: List[List[Int]] = List(List(7), List(2, 2, 3))
```

However If I have list which has duplicates and I want to eliminate the duplicates I can do

```
@ List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.toList
res72: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 2, 3), List(7))
```

You can see the data type of the list above is still List[List[Int]]

Now If I try

```
@ List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.toList.sortBy(_.size)
cmd73.sc:1: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2: <error>) => x$2.size)
val res73 = List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.toList.sortBy(_.size)
                                                                                          ^
Compilation Failed
```

I also tried

```
@ List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.toList.sortBy(x => x.size)
cmd73.sc:1: missing parameter type
val res73 = List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.toList.sortBy(x => x.size)
                                                                                          ^
Compilation Failed
```

I am a little confused. What is the difference between the List[List[Int]] which I build manually vs List[List[Int]] which comes back from the toList function? why is it that I can call `sortBy` on the first one, but I can't call sortBy on the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In above example, `.toSet` is loosing elements type for `List[T]`,

```
def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B] = to[immutable.Set].asInstanceOf[immutable.Set[B]]

scala> List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.foreach(x => println(x))
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type
       List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.foreach(x => println(x))
                                                                           ^
```

But you can verify that it gives right type for simple types `T`,

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1).toSet.toList.sorted
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

So, only specifying a type for `List[T]` is working.

```
scala> List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.foreach((x: List[Int]) => println(x))
List(2, 2, 3)
List(7)

//set type to toSet
scala> List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet[List[Int]].foreach(x => println(x))
List(2, 2, 3)
List(7)
```

To make your example work give either `toSet` (see [another answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50662713/432903)) or elem a type while processing the elem.

```
scala> List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet.toList.sortBy((x: List[Int]) => x.size)
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(7), List(2, 2, 3))
```

And also, you can use `.distinct` instead of `.toSet`

```
scala> List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).distinct.sortBy(_.size)
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(7), List(2, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the definition of [`toSet`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#toSet[B>:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]):

```
def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B]
```

As you can see, there is a type parameter to be inferred. Scala can still infer this in your first example with `toSet`, but the one involving a lambda has more complicated type inference that Scala apparently can't handle. You can fix this by providing the parameter type for your lambda or, more simply, the type parameter to `toSet`:

```
List(List(2, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 2), List(7)).map(_.sorted).toSet[List[Int]].toList
    .sortBy(_.size)
```

As [prayagupd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432903/prayagupd) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50662668/2093695), you can also use `.distinct`.